# Properties inside subclass of NSOperation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsoperation

I call inside asynchronous subclass of NSOperation - NSURLSession, the purpose of this is to be able to load several images at ones and to reflect them in table view. My Queue has next properties:

```
    @property(strong, nonatomic) DataSourse* sourse;
    @property(assign, nonatomic) NSInteger currentCell;
    @property(retain) NSURL *targetURL;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSURLSession* defaultSession;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLSessionDownloadTask* downloadTask;
```

Everytime when user select which image download - I create new queue and initialise it with NSURL and with the number of selected row:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url andRaw:(NSInteger)row
{
    if (![super init])
        return nil;
    [self setTargetURL:url];
    [self setCurrentCell:row];
    self.sourse = [DataSourse sharedManager];
    self.defaultSession = [self configureSession];
    self.isAsynchronous = YES;
    self.isExecuting = YES;
    return self;
}
```

The issue is that during downloading I want update table view, for that i set downloaded image into the Dictionary that is inside the - DataSourse* sourse, that is in my application singleton, to get proper key I need a number of selected row but as I realised, when NSURLSession starts downloading data - all properties in my queue for some reason became like during the first downloading. But NSURLSession is initialised properly and download image correctly.

So as a result in table view always updates just one cell.
Could you advice is this a normal behaviour of NSOperation and NSURLSession, or my fault?
Thank you in advance.